# How to use: Memory Analyzer Tool: Merge Shortest Path to GC Roots: exclude custom field?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-memory-analyzer

[image: You get this popup.]

However, I cannot figure out what to put into -excludes. I have tried adding all four below and I still see the reference I do not want from ClassName.nameOfFieldInClass!

1. org.package.ClassName
2. org.package.ClassName:referent
3. org.package.ClassName:nameOfFieldInClass
4. ClassName:nameOfFieldInClass

and it still displays the references I do not want to see! The documentation isn't very help from the popup:
"Fields of certain classes which should be ignored when finding paths. For example this allows paths through Weak or Soft Reference referents to be ignored."

[The online documentation is even worse](https://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.mat.ui.help%2Freference%2Finspections%2Fpath_to_gc_roots.html) "-excludes  Fields of certain classes which should be ignored when finding paths. For example this allows paths through Weak or Soft Reference referents to be ignored."

What do I put in -excludes?

[Looking through the openjdk source code](https://zgrepcode.com/java/openjdk/10.0.2/java.base/java/lang/ref/reference.java), I see that both WeakReference and SoftReference have a private referent field. As a result, -excludes should be (fullClassName):(variableName). Now I just need to figure out why it's not working on my heap. Maybe the convention is different for a static field?

Answer (score 0):

Ah this is frustrating. It worked when I only had (notice no field/variable):

1. java.lang.ref.WeakReference:referent
2. java.lang.ref.SoftReference:referent
3. org.my.ClassName

However, when I used the below -excludes I got MORE results somehow, even though the query is more restrictive!

1. java.lang.ref.WeakReference:referent
2. java.lang.ref.SoftReference:referent
3. org.my.ClassName
4. org.my.ClassName2